# Purpose of using "as he did" in between a sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read a sentence in my history books which was:

> He reached his destination three weeks later, making a fistful of salt **as he did** and thereby making himself a criminal in the eyes of the law.

Has the phrase "as he did" been used to lay emphasis or is it something else?

Comment: For context this sentence is about [Ghandi's Salt March](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=MWmABAAAQBAJ&pg=PA26&dq=He+reached+his+destination+,+making+a+fistful+of+salt++he+thereby+making+a+criminal+in+the+eyes+of+the+law.&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjOj97q6_TiAhUQh7wKHbhzAU0Q6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=He%20reached%20his%20destination%20%2C%20making%20a%20fistful%20of%20salt%20%20he%20thereby%20making%20a%20criminal%20in%20the%20eyes%20of%20the%20law.&f=false), so "making" refers to production as opposed to earning.

Comment: I'm going to guess this is about Mahatma Gandhi and his famous "salt march"?  Forget "as he did" -- it's just a poorly-written sentence.  Or, at the very least, it's missing some useful punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

In this case "as he did" is used to tie together the different parts of the sentence, clarifying that the act was carried out 'on arrival' rather than beforehand.

In a different context, it might be used to refer to an act that was typical of a person, a specific trait, that might not be easy to define succinctly.